# Creating a Location search from a town or city name only using PHP / MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, location

I've seen numerous articles on using Google Maps and geocoding to search for a radius around a given area, (Haversine formula and the like...) but these all seem to consist of entering a zip / postcode, lat/lng as a search and obviously directly using google maps as a results tool.

I have a database with a series of items in Switzerland each of which is stored with a postcode, lat and lng. My question is how would be the best way of setting up a search with a radius filter from a users location, without the user entering a postcode or a lat/lng location - just entering their town or village? The way I see it is I need to establish the location they've entered is a real place, work out the lat/lng or postcode of this place and then run the search query based on that information; does anyone know of any logic to be able to retrieve that data from anywhere (e.g. enter a town name (not UK) and be able to establish the geo-location from whats enetered then use that to filter results? Ideally, I guess I'd have every village, town and city location stored in a separate table somewhere, which I could query and then work out the radius from there, but its the gathering of the important locative data for a location I can't find how to do?

Any advice on this would be great, thanks. I'm in early stages of this development but will be using PHP/MYSQL to build the core functionality. If anyone knows how some of the larger property portals or other search based locations sites do this that would be great also!

Comment: This isn't really the kind of question that SO can help with.

Comment: Sorry - I know its not code specific, but because there wasn't anything else specifically on location searches with php/mysql without the use of lat/lng/postcode on SO, i was really struggling to find a solution - Maalls has provided some help here which I am grateful for.

Answer (score 0):

The google map API do have a search by place
https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#TextSearchRequests

If you want user to only input the city or village, since you know the country you can append the country into the query.

Comment: Thanks maalls, I'd missed that section of the developer code - I'll work with this and see how I get on!